# jQuery sticky sidebar failing: throws sidebar out of position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys I am trying to make a sticky sidebar but it isn't working how I want it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. What happens when you scroll is that the sidebar gets thrown out of his left position. As you can see in the fiddle the same happens only here I am using an image. Here is a [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PttmhA/7ahsm/7/).
Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance!

jQuery code

```
jQuery(function() { // document ready
        var sideBarTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
        var sideBarLeft = $('#sidebar').offset().left
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
            if(sideBarTop < windowTop) {
                $('#sidebar').css({position: 'fixed', top: 0, left: sideBarLeft});
            }
            else {
                $('#sidebar').css('position', 'static');
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the percentage value you've set on the `#sidebar`. When it's static the percentage value will be based on its parent element however when you switch to `position:fixed` the percentages will be based on the `window/viewport`, you can see the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme